# how to pass the name of the devexpress mvc 4 clicked button in c# to an ajax call of jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I have three panels in the form. Each panel consist of two textboxes and a button. I used devexpress controls and all the controls are loaded dynamically in run time. Now when a I click on the button I want to get the name of that respective button and have to pass it to ajax call in jquery.

As all the controls are loaded in run time dynamically, I don't know how to get the Name of devexpress button.

**Delete button code**

```
@Html.DevExpress().Button(addBtn =>
   {
      addBtn.Name = LoadForm.staticFormId + "_" + LoadForm.VarAnswerIdList[i] + "_" + "Button" + "_" + i + "Add";
        addBtn.Text = "Add New Question";
        addBtn.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
        addBtn.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e) { AddNewQuestion(); }";
    }).GetHtml();
```

**Delete javascript function**

```
function DeleteQuestion(s, e) {
        debugger;
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Action("_DeleteQuestion", "LoadEditableForm")',
           data: "&varChangeQuestionDetail=" + s.getName(),
           beforeSend: function () {
               lpCPartial.Show();
           },
           success: function (response) {
               debugger;
               $("#genForm").html(response);


               lpCPartial.Hide();
           }
       });
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have access to the DOM element which initiated the `.click()` event through your parameter `e`.  With that, you could get the name in pure JS like so:

```
   e.getAttribute("name");
```

Or through jQuery:

```
$(e).prop("name");
```

As to passing it through your `.ajax()` call, I would construct a JSON object, such that your code ends up looking like this:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '@Url.Action("_DeleteQuestion", "LoadEditableForm")',
       data: {varChangeQuestionDetail: $(e).prop('name') },
       beforeSend: function () {
           lpCPartial.Show();
       },
       success: function (response) {
           debugger;
           $("#genForm").html(response);


           lpCPartial.Hide();
       }
   });
```